# In "Kiss Him Not Me" how does Kae just automatically become beautiful by just going to sleep?

Tags: kiss-him-not-me

I've just been wondering this since I started watching it and couldn't figure it out so I hope someone can help!

Comment: That plot detail was so stupid, I stopped watching after the first episode. Plain, heavy, teenage girl gets depressed when her favorite character dies.  She shuts herself in a room for about a week, loses weight, and becomes very attractive. I believe this is commonly referred to as an a**-pull, written only to get the plot to where they want it.  You're supposed to ignore that it makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 3):

She didn't become "Automatically beautiful just by going to sleep" Instead, out of depression of her favorite anime guy dying, she locked herself in her room for a week without any food, therefore reducing her body fat and making her thin.